# Is it possible to have a locale-independent 24 hour java date format

Tags: java, date-format

Is there a way to create a java DateFormat that in every Locale is set to 24 hours?

If I use SimpleDateFormat with a format string I lose the locale independence, which is not what i want but I want to be able to determine that in every locale the time format of the date is in 24h and I have not found how to do that with DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat. E.g. when I set the locale to English I always get "AM/PM" times which I do not want.

Comment: Could you post an example of Strings you want to parse? Along with what you have tried?

Comment: if you use format string "HH:mm" - you always get 24h time format. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: This is not about parsing, just formatting. I tried DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date()) which gives me output like "11/14/15 2:05 PM" and I do not see how I can modify this using any of the setters of DateFormat and if I use a format String I lose the locale independence.

Comment: with same format string you can parse and also can format

Comment: I could of course use the combination of a DateFormat and a SimpleDateFormat and only use the latter for time with "HH:mm" as you suggested.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));